# Definitions which were chosen because we write functions on the left

Tags: functions, notation, big-list

Writing function application as a left action has been baked into mathematics since the Bernoullis in the 1700s (cf. [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636332/the-origin-of-the-function-fx-notation)). Because of this tradition, a lot of mathematics notation has been chosen to complement this.

One (perhaps shocking) example is the commutator $[a,b]$ in a group. Traditionally we use left group actions (to be in line with left-function application), and so the conjugation action is $g \cdot h = ghg^{-1}$. This leads us to define $[a,b] = aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ (so that, among other things,
$s \cdot [a,b] = [s \cdot a, s \cdot b]$).

It has become accepted to instead use right group actions, denoted $h^g = g^{-1}hg$, and with this convention we would instead write $[a,b] = a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$. This gives the identity $[a,b]^s = [a^s, b^s]$.

---

There are lots of places in mathematics where we have an arbitrary choice to make. Left/Right Cosets in algebra, Left/Right Linearity of the complex inner product, etc. I am curious if any of these conventions have to do with functions acting on the left or the right, as in the above example.

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a convention backed in history (as you say): there is no "deep" reason for it and no reason to change it. Probably the motivation is only the Western way of writing from left to right: thus, it seems natural to symbolize "function $f$ applied to argument $x$" with $f:x$ or $f(x)$.

Comment: It's also highly related to the convection in linear algebra that we have to consider *column vectors* for connecting linear maps to (left) matrix multiplication. In contrast, there are algebra books that rigorously put function applications to the right.

Comment: I think that there is a good argument for adopting a notation in which functions act on the right.  For example, if we have $$X \overset{f}{\to} Y \overset{g}{\to} Z, $$ then we have a function $g \circ f$, which reads backwards from the diagram.  Related difficulties arise in fractal geometry, where iterated function systems are often of interest:  if $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_n)$ is a multiindex and $f^{\alpha}$ denotes a composition of maps, is $f_{\alpha_1}$ the first map we apply, or the last one?  That being said, the acts-on-the left convention is here to stay. ;)

Comment: @Mauro I agree with you all! I'm not trying to switch to functions on the right! I just realized that the definitions of conjugation and commutator are based in our (arbitrary) choice of left vs right. I'm curious if there's other examples of this.

Comment: Ordinal multiplication is not commutative. The product $AB$ of ordinals $A, B$ is the ordinal which is order-isomorphic to the lexicographic order on $B\times A$, and the lexicography is English (or German or ...), not Hebrew (nor Arabic ...). Because someone in the 20th century (J. von Neumann?) liked it.