# Consequences of using left-to-right composition

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Personally, I find left to right composition much more natural, but I have seem to come across an instance where using this notation gives different results.

Let $G$ be a group and define $\phi: G \to \operatorname{Aut} G$ as:
$$
\phi : g \mapsto I_g
$$
where:
\begin{align}
I_g : G &\to G \\
x &\mapsto g x g^{-1}\\
\end{align}
Then $\phi$ is a homomorphism since:
\begin{align}
a,b \in G \implies \phi(ab) = I_{ab} = I_a I_b = \phi(a)\phi(b)
\end{align}
where $I_{ab} = I_a I_b$ follows from the fact that:
$$
I_{ab} (x) = ab x b^{-1} a^{-1} = I_a (I_b (x))
$$
However, the preceding is not true if we use left to right notation since $(x) I_{ab} = (x) I_b I_a $ and not $(x) I_a I _b$. So if we use left to right notation, we instead have:
$$
(ab) \phi = (b) \phi (a)\phi = I_b I_a
$$

So, what gives? If notation can affect results, how can one justify the use of different notations?

Comment: What gives is how you interpret $I_{ab}=I_aI_b$. The way I read it is that applying $I_{ab}$ is the same as applying $I_b$ *first* and then applying $I_a$ *after*. So in the new notation, $I_{ab}=I_b I_a$ is unsurprising since you're applying $I_b$ *first* and then applying $I_a$ *after*. So to make how one reads right to left composition consistent, one must have $I_{ab}=I_b I_a$.

Comment: This is possibly related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387823/definitions-which-were-chosen-because-we-write-functions-on-the-left) old question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following statement is independent from any definition of the composition $\circ$:

If $G$ is a group, then $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is a group with multiplication defined by $(\alpha \cdot \beta)(g) := \alpha(\beta(g))$. Also, conjugation provides a homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$.

The following statement *is* dependent on a definition of the composition $\circ$:

If $G$ is a group, then $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is a group with multiplication defined by $\alpha \cdot \beta := \alpha \circ \beta$. Also, conjugation provides a homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$.

As you can see, this is not related to the conjugation map. It is really about the definition of the multiplication in the group $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$. When you are using the more common definition of $\circ$, the statements are the same. But when you are using the other "left to right" definition of composition, which is more commonly denoted as $\,;\,$ at least in computer science circles (also in order to avoid any confusion with $\circ$), then $a \cdot \beta := \alpha \,;\, \beta$ actually yields the opposite group $\mathrm{Aut}(G)^{\mathrm{op}}$ (for the usual definition of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$), and the second statement will not be true anymore when $\circ$ is just replaced with $;$.

Given this, I am not convinced that any statements change their meaning when you change the notation. You just gotta be very careful to change the notation *consistently*. Here, you forgot to also change it in the definition of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$. When you want to get a homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$, you need to define $\alpha \cdot \beta := \beta \,;\, \alpha$ (which is $\alpha \circ \beta$).

For a more drastic example (just to illustrate the point): Let's say I define natural number literals by $-1 := S(0)$, $-2 := S(S(0))$, $-3 := S(S(S(0)))$, etc., where $S$ is the successor function. So $\{\dotsc,-2,-1,0\}$ is the set of natural numbers. Now you might think: "Hey, the set of natural numbers doesn't have any smallest element anymore!". But you got fooled by the notation. $0$ is still the smallest element when you define $<$ as usual, because it will give you $0 < -1 < -2 < \cdots$.

Comment: Of course, you can also get a homomorphism into the opposite automorphism group by letting $I_g : x \mapsto g^{-1}xg$. This will usually be the best place to put the flip, I think.